React 18 new way of state update or not?
I encountered a peculiar issue with state updates in React, not a bug my code was working fine but I feel a bit weird. Initially, I have a product state that contains all the products fetched from the API:
const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);

I created a function to change a product's information. Even though I didn't update the previous products' state, the description still changes to the new one:
const handleChangeProduct = async ({ productId }: Product) => {
  const exitsProduct = products.find(({ id }) => id === productId);
  exitsProduct.description = "example desc";
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.VITE_APP_API_URL}/products/add`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(exitsProduct),
    }
  );
  const responseObj = await response.json();
  // Update the products state, I don't know why the products state is update the description to `example desc`.
  if (responseObj?.success) {
    setProducts(products);
  }
} 

Since I began working with React, this is the method I have considered correct for updating state.
const updatedProducts = products.map((product) => {
  if (product.id === productId) {
    return {
     ...product,
     description: product.description,
    }
  }
  return product;
});
setProducts(updatedProducts);

If this is due to my lack of understanding about ReactJS, please let me know. Can we actually update the new product state even if we copy the state to a new constant?

I think you know that the handleChangeProduct shown breaks the fundamental rule of React state: Don't directly modify state members. I think you're asking why you see the updated description if the function is doing it wrong.
It's because React may re-render your component for other reasons, and when re-rendering, it will use the current properties of the objects in the state, including properties that were updated incorrectly. The problem with updating them incorrectly is that there's no guarantee of when or whether React will render the change you've made. To correctly ensure React renders the change, you need to do what your updatedProducts function does: Create a new array, and a new object for the product you want to update.
Here's an example. Run the following, and click the "Update Just Property" button. Notice that nothing happens. But then click the "Update Property and Counter" button, and notice that both the counter and the property are re-rendered.


const { useState, useRef } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [object, setObject] = useState({ property: 0 });

    const update = (updateCounter) => {
        ++object.property; // <=== WRONG, don't do this
        setObject(object); // <=== Does nothing
        if (updateCounter) {
            setCounter((c) => c + 1);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="button"
                value="Update Just Property"
                onClick={() => update(false)}
            />
            <input
                type="button"
                value="Update Property and Counter"
                onClick={() => update(true)}
            />
            <div>counter: {counter}</div>
            <div>property: {object.property}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




Side note: The setProducts(products); call in handleChangeProduct isn't guaranteed to do anything (and in my experience doesn't), because products (the array) hasn't changed (at least not in the code shown), even though a property on one of the objects in the array has changed.

Thank you, but if I remove the setProducts(products); part, the description is not changed!

@VietNguyen - Well, there are no guarantees that React won't render, just a lack of guarantee that it will (and I can't replicate that -- can you provide a [mre]?), React can decide to re-render your component whenever it likes. But there is no question that handleChangeProduct updates the object incorrectly.

It's so weird, here is my code screen and the red line, if I remove it, the state is never updated. Please take a look here https://ibb.co/g3GkfTk. I already tried to reproduce the problem here but not succeed codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-state-4nvrfr

@VietNguyen - Again, there are no guarantees what React will do with an incorrect update. The fundamental thing here is, if you want to update a product in that array, your code in updatedProducts is the correct way to do it. If you directly modify an object in state, you have no idea when or whether that change will be rendered.

I found the answer for this, this is because I using react-modal and somehow this modal triggers the change. You can see it here codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-state-4nvrfr. The exitsProduct.description = "example desc"; never update the state actually!

@VietNguyen - That's a relief, I was really wondering. :-) Good find!
